# WAPPALYZER vs Netcraft vs builtwith

Tags: asp.net, node.js, builtwith

I am trying to find out the technology stack of a site (Varzesh3.com). I tried different tools such as WAPPALYZER vs Netcraft vs builtwith. All of them except WAPPALYZER show that the website is built using ASP.net. But WAPPALYZER says that Node.js, PHP, and Java, and Drupal are also used! Why is that? Are the results of WAPPALYZER reliable? Which output is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, those programs check for file name ends, session cookies and html attributes to get a guess, I love to use Wappalyzer every once in a while when Im browsing and I think it is the most reliable in most cases.

It is possible that some HTML attributes in the website make Wappalyzer guess other technologies so one suggestion I have is go to the Wappalyzer Website Technologies List at https://www.wappalyzer.com/technologies and look for your website there to get more reliable results